# Is it possible to create a custom PDF or sheet in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a working model of my company's PO creation software written with GSpread currently sending data to a Google Sheet, then printing that as a PDF. The issue with this is there is a limit to the amount of queries I can make to the Google Sheets API, and sometimes that limit is hit. The other problem is that only one person can be using it at a time because it's a shared Sheet.

Is it possible to create something similar to this locally? Maybe an XL file, or a PDF?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR3DK.png

I have the logic for everything else written out, I just need to figure out how I can send my defined variables containing the info to a similar format locally.

Comment: You may want to take a look at ReportLab

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your actual situation, if you have the possibility to continue to use Google Spreadsheet, for example, how about using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script as an API? You can retrieve the PDF data by sending the values to Web Apps. In this case, there are no Quotas for using Sheets API. And you can use the Web Apps with the exclusive processing by using the lock service. But if this was not suitable for your actual situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually several options to create PDFs on Python like ReportLabs, XHTML2PDF, pyQT, rinohtype etc.

I'll leave a few links down below that you might find helpful:

1. https://gearheart.io/blog/how-generate-pdf-files-python-xhtml2pdf-weasyprint-or-unoconv/
2. https://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2009/08/16/get-your-job-done-faster-with-pypdf/
3. https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit
4. http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/